# Custom middleware block raised exceptions's backtrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I need some advices. I'm working on my first Rack middleware. However, when an exception is raised from, lets say, a controller, I don't get the full exception's backtrace since my middleware is apparently the last to have the hand on it :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `accessible?' for "zFhY3ksiR4UdtGH3ZHs3":String):
   app/middleware/content_negotiation.rb:28:in `_call'
   app/middleware/content_negotiation.rb:20:in `call'
```

Instead of the real backtrace, i.e something like that :

```
[ 0] "/.../lib/doorkeeper/doorkeeper_for.rb:17:in `validate_token'",
[ 1] "/.../lib/doorkeeper/helpers/filter.rb:9:in `block in doorkeeper_for'",
```

Line 20 of the custom middleware corresponds to :

```
 def call(env)
  dup._call(env)
 end
```

Line 28 corresponds to that line of the `_call` :

```
status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
```

What's the best practice for a custom middleware to be transparent/non-blocking in that case? Should I rescue from that middleware and show the exception/backtrace ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is in `app/middleware/content_negotiation.rb:28` and `app/middleware/content_negotiation.rb:20`?

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: Having the same problem - any way to fix this? Rails 4.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rail's backtrace cleaners

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html

Under `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb`

you can add the following line which will silence your custom middleware errors

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |line| line =~ /app\/middleware/ }
```